# Number Theory Congruent and Modulo problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have given a problem and I found out that I have a problem with explanation in words. I can solve it with numbers however when it comes to a problem where I have to explain in words, I don't know how to write.

Given problem: For all integers $a$ and $b$ and positive integer $m$, is the following statement true?

$$a \equiv b \pmod m \implies 2a \equiv 2b \pmod m$$

My solution: True. Assume that $a=6$ and $b=4$ modulo 2. Modulo 2 divides $a-b$. 2 divides 6-4 which gives 1. Therefore it is true.

I am aware of the lack of words to explain and I need help.

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: The given problem says "for all integers," not "for a=6,b=4,m=2." Is English a second language for you? What you want to do is *unpack the meaning* of the phrase "a is congruent to b modulo m": this means that m|(a-b), which means a-b=mk for some k. In this case, we have 2(a-b)=m(2k) so m|(2a-2b) so 2a is congruent to 2b modulo m. The idea is to change between equivalent formulations of a statement and make deductions.

Comment: When you want to prove a certain statement that holds for every number, you shouldn't look just at one specific case, you should try to give general proof.

Comment: Yes, I am an exchange student and it's quite difficult to learn English and i try my best to solve the problem. I understand that "a is congruent to b modulo m": this means that m|(a-b), which means a-b=mk for some k. BUT if 2a triple lines 2b (mod m) when m=2 a=6 and b=4 then it can be solved right? i am sorry to confuse you all

Comment: I chose a=6, and b=4.

Comment: You proved that it holds for just one specific case, but the problem is to prove that it works for every given numbers, that satisfy the condition. You can't apply your way, because there are infinite amount of cases and you can't check whether all of them are true.

Proof even for 100, 10000 or 100000 cases won't help you, because maybe there is a special case for which the statement doesn't hold and you've missed it. You must give a general prove to the statement, not for specific case.

Answer (score 2):

You need to show that this is true for all integers. Because it satisfies some examples does not say that it is true for all integers. To prove the statement you can use definition:

> $a\equiv b\pmod m$ if and only if  there exists an integer $k$ such
>   that $a-b=km$.

Put this where you need in your proof and it will be done.

Comment: so to give a general prove, i must use the definition instead of make specific cases? Thank you my friend. that was very helpful

Comment: For this proof, it is enough. You take $a,b,m$ be integers, then assume that $a \equiv b \pmod m$ (because this is a premise of the statement), then you apply definition, so you conclude that $2a - 2b=k'm$, for some $k'$, and apply again defintion to obtain $2a\equiv 2b \pmod m$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little help.

We know that for every 4 numbers that satisfy this:

$a \equiv b \pmod m \quad c \equiv d \pmod m$

the following statement is true:

$ac \equiv bd \pmod m$

Can you make an application of the statement in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Well proving this explicit case.

You know $a \equiv b\ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$ then 
m$\mid$a - b $\Rightarrow $ a - b = mk, for some k where k is an integer. Then now 2(a - b) = 2mk $\Rightarrow $ 2a - 2b = m(2k), now notice that 2k is also an integer so m$\mid$2a - 2b $\Rightarrow $ $2a \equiv 2b\ (\textrm{mod}\ m)$